# Client-side JWT role-based authorization

Tags: javascript, security, authorization, jwt

I understand a JWT can contain some information about the user's role to be verified against on the server, e.g. in `scope`, such that a non-role user will not be able to access data from certain endpoints secured to that role.

```
{
  "iss": "http://issuer.com",
  "exp": 1300819380,
  "scopes": ["customer", "supplier", "seller"],
  "sub": "user@issuer.com"
}
```

So the data is safe. But let's say I have a dashboard, the features of which I would like to prevent a user from viewing.

Considering the JWT can be tampered with client-side, how do you go about securing such pages in an SPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the client-side code can be tampered with and so it is not a safe place for logic that restricts the user's access.

Assuming that the features of the dashboard are actually capabilities provided by an API (e.g. viewing data retrieved through a GET request, or manipulating data through a POST, PUT, DELETE request), you could protect those API endpoints instead.  So even if a malicious user tampered with the client-side code, they would not be getting or changing any protected data.

But to your specific question about how to secure the pages in a SPA, there is no such a way.  Even if the code is obfuscated, it is still all there for a sophisticated user to dissect and alter arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks for the inisght. Actually the features of the dashboard I mentioned are loaded within the single-page-app, and are independent of API data. I would like to protect those features as well. I understand a sophisticated attacker could bypass whatever client-side measures I take, however I'm looking for a setup that protects against the other 99%.